# how to play video from blob uri in gstreamer

Tags: qt, webkit, gstreamer, qtwebkit, webrtc

i am doing a project in which i am trying to implement webrtc in qt webkit. I have managed to make the webcam on but i am not able to show any video. While debuging i saw i am getting the url of the stream from webcam as `"blob:http://192.168.70.95:8080/b90eaeb3-b50e-48ff-8ff6-e62caf8d72cf"`. almost similar to that in the chrome. But when i give it to gstreamer to play the stream it says `No URI handler implemented for "blob". (url=blob:http://192.168.70.95:8080/b90eaeb3-b50e-48ff-8ff6-e62caf8d72cf)`. 
Is there any way to play the blob uri using gstreamer. i am using a play bin for this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if dataurisrc can help. It might need some modifications though.